# How to install firefox addon with silent mode?

Tags: c#, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I've already posted my extension in firefox store (spread by myself).

My clients wanna use my desktop application to install an extention to Firefox from Firefox store with silentmode.

I wanna use Windows registry [like that for chrome extention](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/external_extensions#registry), but i am ready to consider options.

Which steps should I take?
P.s. desktop app is WPF application(C#).

Comment: Firefox [removed this feature](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2019/10/31/firefox-to-discontinue-sideloaded-extensions/) recently.

Answer (score 0):

Thank [you](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3959875) for your comment !

I solve my issue without silent mode, but minimized user participation with the following code.

You should start firefox.exe with arguments.

```
Process.Start("firefox.exe", "https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/file/your_unique_number");
```